# Xdebug + PhpStorm does not work for WordPress site setup with localwp

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'd like to use PhpStorm's zero configuration debugging as described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html I had it set up a while ago and I know it works.

However, when I listen to PHP debug connections and load the site, I get the following error/screen and I don't know what to do here, why it breaks on that script:

[image]

Here are the details of the site I've pulled to my machine via localwp from wpengine, note it's `https` (I also tried with https box ticked this didn't affect the issue I'm having):

[image]

Here is the server I've added in PhpStorm preferences and it validates via "Validate Debugger Configuration on Web Server":

[image]

[image]

And there are my Xdebug preferences:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

**This also happens when using Xdebug + PhpStorm add-on provided by localwp app**. I've added run configuration via localwp app and here are the settings that I see (below).
Note it doesn't recognise it as `https`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run Debug "Local" it still breaks on the same script:

[image]

[image]

Versions:
PhpStorm v2021.1
localwp v6.0.0 (but also didn't work in the previous version)

Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it, please? I'd really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: *> I don't know what to do here, why it breaks on that script* - Because your app goes through this file & IDE receives a corresponding request to process it. Try enabling XDebug logging, launch debugging again & share generated xdebug log: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs

Comment: Your 1st and especially last screenshot -- it shows that tha file that PHP is executing right now / Xdebug trying to debug (`/application/Local.app/Contents/Resources/extraResources/local-bootstrap.php`) is located outside of the project (which makes perfect sense as it appears to belong to LocalWP itself). You need to reference that file somehow .. or exclude from being executed by PHP at all. To reference: try adding the parent folder of that file in `Preferences | PHP | Include Paths` (meant for 3rd party code/libraries)